# PyAutoGUI's alert() and pysmsgbox fails even after installing Tkinter

Tags: pyautogui

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.alert("msg")
```

I just want to use msgbox with pyautogui, but there's something error occurred when I execute this code. (tkinter module is already installed in my python version)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/han-yohan/development/PYTHON_LABS/PYTHON_RPA/01. DesktopRPA/message_box.py", line 3, in <module>
    pyautogui.alert('Start?')
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymsgbox/__init__.py", line 110, in _alertTkinter
    assert TKINTER_IMPORT_SUCCEEDED, "Tkinter is required for pymsgbox"
AssertionError: Tkinter is required for pymsgbox
```

I tried reinstall tkinter and pyautogui module, but still not work

Comment: What operating system are you on? What happens when you run `import tkinter` from the interactive shell?